# Adding extra scrolling space into DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

How to add an extra vertical scrolling space into the regular WPF DataGrid to provide an ability to scroll the last rows closer to the middle of the screen?

I've searched for the solution but the only suggestion I found is "adding empty rows to the end of the list".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty easy by using external ScrollViewer:

```
  <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <StackPanel>
      <DataGrid ItemSource={Binding MyCollection}/>
      <Rectangle Height="{Binding BottomSpace}"/>
     </StackPanel>
  </ScrollViewer>
```